# User Authentication - Passing user Id around to each page - Best Practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, cookies, oauth

I am working on a Sinatra based app and currently using LinkedIn for authentication. Some content on my page is db-based and hence I need user id for that user before I route someone.

I am trying to understand usually how websites keep track of user id on each page ? Some ideas  I have:

1] Put the user id in a cookie and perform session mgmt through that.

2] Use a global user-id variable. I am not sure how this would work in my app since there would be multiple users etc.

3] Pass the user id around to each page (haml/html) as a local variable and have it passed back to the route in params !

2] and 3] => sounds complicated.

Whats the usual way to handle this problem ?
Any suggestions for gems etc that I can use.

Comment: just an fyi - sessions are disabled by default in sinatra

Comment: From sessions I meant saving uniq user id in users cookies. I was able to do that in sinatra and push it to heroku

Answer (score 0):

1] is likely the 'correct' answer, however if you already have access to the session for the specific user, you already know who they are so the cookie is just additional 'stuff' that the server and browser will have to send. In other words, if your server already has a session to which you have access, and that session already maps to the user, you are already following the that user around.

2 and 3] require state management or doing server side processing on the page's content delivered to the client.